# printing too much stars

Tags: c

I type this code on Ubuntu 14.04

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {

  int i, j, n;
  scanf("%",&n);
  for (i=0;i<=n;i++){
    for (j=0;j<=i;j++){
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

but it print too much stars and it Continue until I close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {

int i, j, n;
scanf("%d",&n);
for (i=0;i<=n;i++){
    for (j=0;j<=i;j++){
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

You forgot to tell scanf you were reading in an integer by using the %d argument

Comment: Thank you what a silly question I made.

Comment: @Vesal75: And so the extremely basic mistake is that you did not **debug** your program. As soon as you hit that line, a debugger would have shown that `n` contained a random value and not what you entered. By the way, look at your compiler settings. Mine can warn for such mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

There is mistake in

> scanf("%",&n);

it will be:

> scanf("%d",&n);

to tell the complier that the value of n is an integer type.